# Vue-ApexChart Set color on individual bars based on another series value

Tags: vue.js, apexcharts

I'm using ApexChart-Vue and my graph has two series one bar and one line. The line is the goal for that specific date and the bar is the value for that date. I'm trying to set the color of the bar to red if the value is lower than the goal and to green if the value is equal or higher that the goal.

I understand that a can add a function to the colors array, but only one function per series.

Basically I want to do way the doc says here: https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/colors/

```
colors: [function({ value, seriesIndex, w }) {
  if (value < 55) {
      return '#7E36AF'
  } else {
      return '#D9534F'
  }
}, function({ value, seriesIndex, w }) {
  if (value < 111) {
      return '#7E36AF'
  } else {
      return '#D9534F'
  }
}]
```

But I need to pass the the goal for the current date into the function some how.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you wish to be able to customize the values 55 and 111 based on some changing goal eg the target on Bar 1 is 10 but on Bar 2 is 20.

According to the source code, color functions receive the following object:

```
{
     seriesIndex: this.seriesIndex, // the data series being coloured
     dataPointIndex: opts.dataPointIndex, // the index for that bar
     value: opts.value, // the value for that bar
     w: w // ??
}
```

My approach would be to store the targets as an array then just access the threshold for each date using the index value

```
colors: [
   function ({ value, dataPointIndex }) {
     if (targets[dataPointIndex] > ) {
          return Colors.red
     } else {      
          return Colors.green
     }
}]
```